¿Cómo dar solución al error: ORA-00001: restricción única violada?
recién inicio con la programación en c# y tengo la siguiente consulta.
Necesito hacer un CRUD a una base de datos en Oracle, hasta el momento solo he logrado realizar la consulta, pero al momento de hacer un INSERT me muestra el siguiente error:"Error al guardar el registro: ORA-00001: restricción única (JOSE.PK_CONDUCTOR) violada".
Para lograr la inserción primero cree un método que obtiene el valor máximo del campo
CVE_CONDUCTOR y lo regresa sumándole 1.

    private decimal ObtenerNuevoConductor()
    {
        OraConexion oraConexion = new OraConexion();
        oraConexion.Open();
    
        decimal nuevoCVEConductor = 0;
        string consultaSql = "SELECT MAX(CVE_CONDUCTOR) AS MAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR FROM JOSE.CONDUCTOR";
    
        using (OracleCommand comando = new OracleCommand(consultaSql, oraConexion.conexion))
        {
            using (OracleDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    nuevoCVEConductor =
                        Convert.IsDBNull(reader["MAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR"]) ? 0 :
                        Convert.ToDecimal(reader["MAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR"]);
                }
            }
        }
        oraConexion.Close();
        return nuevoCVEConductor + 1;
    }

Después llamo a este mismo método desde otro en donde ya realizo el INSERT
public ActionResult GuardarConductor(string claveConductor, string nombre, string licencia, int residuo, int documento, string calle, int nomina)
{
    try
    {
        //VALIDACIONES GENERALES
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(claveConductor) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(nombre) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(licencia) ||
            residuo == 0 ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(calle))
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Todos los campos son obligatorios y no pueden estar vacíos o con espacios." });
        }

        //VALIDACIONES ESPECIFICAS
        Regex regexSoloLetras = new Regex("^[A-Z ]+$");
        Regex regexSoloNumeros = new Regex("^[0-9]{5}$");
        Regex regexNomina = new Regex("^[0-9]{1,5}$");

        //MENSAJES DE ERROR
        if (!regexSoloLetras.IsMatch(nombre))
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "El campo NOMBRE solo puede contener letras mayúsculas." });
        }
        if (regexSoloLetras.IsMatch(calle))
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "El campo CALLE solo puede contener letras mayúsculas." });
        }
        if (!regexSoloNumeros.IsMatch(nomina.ToString()))
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "El campo N° NOMINA debe contener exactamente 5 números. En caso de no tener colocar 0." });
        }

        //Obtener el nuevo valor de CVE_CONDUCTOR
        decimal nuevoCVEConductor = ObtenerNuevoConductor();

        OraConexion oraConexion = new OraConexion();
        oraConexion.Open();

        string consultaSql = @"INSERT INTO JOSE.CONDUCTOR (CVE_CONDUCTOR, NOMBRE, NUM_LICENCIA, CERTIF_PARA_RESIDUO, ESTA_DOCTO, CALLE, NUM_NOMINA) VALUES (:cveConductor, :nombre, :nLicencia, :certifResiduo, :estDocto, :calle, :numNomina)";

        using(OracleCommand comando = new OracleCommand(consultaSql, oraConexion.conexion))
        {
            comando.Parameters.Add(":cveConductor", nuevoCVEConductor);
            comando.Parameters.Add(":nombre", nombre);
            comando.Parameters.Add(":nLicencia", licencia);
            comando.Parameters.Add(":certifResiduo", residuo);
            comando.Parameters.Add(":estDocto", documento);
            comando.Parameters.Add(":calle", calle);
            comando.Parameters.Add(":numNomina", nomina);

            int filasAfectadas = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oraConexion.Close();

            if(filasAfectadas > 0)
            {
                return Json(new { success = true, message = "Registro guardado exitosamente." });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error al guardar el registro" });
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error al guardar el registro: " + ex.Message });
    }
}

En mi vista trabajo con javascript y cree una función para guardar el formulario
function obtenerDatos() {
    return {
        CVE_CONDUCTOR: $('#txtclave').val(),
        NOMBRE: $('#txtnombre').val(),
        NUM_LICENCIA: $('#txtlicencia').val(),
        CERTIF_PARA_RESIDUO: $('#txtcertificado').val(),
        ESTA_DOCTO: $('#cboestadocto').val(),
        RFC: $('#txtrfc').val(),
        CALLE: $('#txtcalle').val(),
        NUM_EXT: $('#txtexterior').val(),
        COLONIA: $('#txtcolonia').val(),
        CVE_MUNICIPIO: $('#txtmunicipio').val(),
        CVE_ESTADO: $('#txtestado').val(),
        COD_POSTAL: $('#txtcpostal').val(),
        NUM_NOMINA: $('#txtnomina').val(),
    };
}

function guardar() {

    if ($("#contenedor").valid()) {
        var conductor = obtenerDatos();
        var cveConductor = $('#txtclave').val();
        var nombre = $('#txtnombre').val();
        var licencia = $('#txtlicencia').val();
        var residuo = $('#cboresiduo').val() == 1 ? true : false;
        var documento = $('#cboestadocto').val() == 1 ? true : false;
        var calle = $('#txtcalle').val();
        var nomina = $('#txtnomina').val();

        $.ajax({
            url:  "/Listado/GuardarConductor",
            type: 'POST',
            content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {
                cveConductor: cveConductor,
                calle: calle,
                nombre: nombre,
                licencia: licencia,
                residuo: residuo, 
                documento: documento,
                nomina: nomina
            },
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (data.success) {
                    console.log(response.message);
                    cerrarModal();
                    tabladata.ajax.reload(); //actualizar tabla despues de guardar
                } else {
                    console.error(response.message);
                    $('#mensajeError').text(response.message).show(); 
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

Solo había intentado hacer el INSERT con un solo campo y si funcionaba agregaba el resto, pero no he logrado solucionar el problema. Me podrían ayudar con esto por favor

posiblemente ese error sea debido a que tu código está intentando insertar un valor en la columna CVE_CONDUCTOR que ya existe en CONDUCTOR.

Has ejecutado paso a paso el código? qué valor devuelve el select(max)? dicho esto, el código va a fallar tarde o temprano si hay concurrencia. La solución es usar secuencias y no select(max), aunque en una prueba básica o un sistema sin concurrencia te debiera funcionar.

Se ve un poco confuso el código en C para interactuar con Oracle (debe ser porque trabajo directamente es con PL/SQL y SQL de Oracle).
Lo que veo es que una vez obtiene el valor máximo de la columna CVE_CONDUCTOR, le debe sumar 1 (uno) antes de insertar el registro.
Lo otro que debe tener en cuenta es que la primera vez que se ejecute el MAX() el valor resultante es nulo, no sé como lo maneje en C#.
En ese caso deberá asignarle a la variable 1.
Y en los demás casos sumarle 1.
Le recomiendo eliminar las validaciones de si están o no en mayúsculas las palabras, la mejor práctica es pasar el texto todo a mayúsculas con la función que tenga en C#.
Ejemplo en el lenguaje procedimental PL/SQL de Oracle:
Declare
      --
      Procedure pInsertar_conductor(iNombre        CONDUCTOR.nombre%type, 
                                    iLicencia      CONDUCTOR.NUM_LICENCIA%type, 
                                    iCertifResiduo CONDUCTOR.CERTIF_PARA_RESIDUO%type, 
                                    iestDocto      CONDUCTOR.ESTA_DOCTO%type, 
                                    iCalle         CONDUCTOR.CALLE%type, 
                                    iNumNomina     CONDUCTOR.NUM_NOMINA%type 
                                   )
      is
        nuMAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR number;
        nuCveConductor      number;
      Begin
        SELECT MAX(CVE_CONDUCTOR)
        into  nuMAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR
        FROM CONDUCTOR;
        --
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line('nuMAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR='||nuMAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR);
        --
        if nuMAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR is null then
           nuMAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR:=1;
        Else
           nuMAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR:=nuMAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR+1;
        End if;
        --
        nuCveConductor:=nuMAX_CVE_CONDUCTOR;
        --
        INSERT INTO CONDUCTOR 
                   (CVE_CONDUCTOR,
                    NOMBRE, 
                    NUM_LICENCIA, 
                    CERTIF_PARA_RESIDUO, 
                    ESTA_DOCTO, 
                    CALLE, 
                    NUM_NOMINA
                   ) 
        VALUES (nuCveConductor, 
                iNombre, 
                iLicencia, 
                iCertifResiduo, 
                iestDocto, 
                iCalle, 
                iNumNomina
                );
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Filas insertadas='||sql%rowcount);
      End;
    Begin
      pInsertar_conductor('Pedro picapiedra',
                          'p00001',
                          'cdx002',
                          'vigente',
                          'Av Rocadura # 23',
                          12345
                          );
    End;

